# Expandable listview not to select rows

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i checked the documentation & tried few ways to disable the click of group items of expandable listview. None came to use.

There is a method `isChildSelectable` in [Expandablelistadapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html). But not isGroupSelectable. I tried manyways like disabling the click of list item etc.. no luck.  I want to disable the click of certain listview group items.

Answer (score 3):

```
 expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                    View childView, int groupPosition, long id) {
                if (groupPosition == desirePosition) {// give your condition here
//temporary condition is given
                    return true; // the expander cannot be collapsed
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, Yes i will mark it.  i want to show few actions once user taps on a list item. these options are always common. Like when i click on a number it should show call and sms option. below the selected number. i have chosen expandable listiview. Can i implement the same by hiding and showing dummy view to listview?

Comment: @Naruto Yes its possible

Comment: +1 for your answer, i will test it. actually i wanted a animation kind of dropdown. So i thought of choosing expandable listview. any example you have? please

Comment: @Naruto here the question is for the expand and collapse for the item only an i guess from the above code it should resolved. its android expandable listview native method only.  for collapse default animation you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup%28int,%20boolean%29

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will check, i'm checking your code in my sample app. thanks for your help. i'll check and getback

Comment: But, i checked the above code, i'm getting the selection appearance?. anyway to avoid that. i.e like user feels click appearance but no action. I want to get rid of click option too

Comment: @Naruto you can set selector to that as a transparent or give null check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector

Comment: can't i set selector to list item, actually few of my row items should not be selectable. Your answer is good. but i get click appearance, i dont want that also.